# I am unable to align the glypicon image and text associated with it in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="float:left">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">E-Store</a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
      <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart aria-hidden="true"></span> <a href="signup.html">Cart </a></li>
      <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user aria-hidden="true">    </span><a href="aboutus.html">Settings</a></li>
      <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off aria-hidden="true"></span><a href="contactus.html" >Logout </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here, I am unable to get the cart image and text cart in one line. How to go about for getting text right side to image?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the glyphicon inside the link:

```
<a href="signup.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span> Cart</a>
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dutft5zr/1/)

And be carefull, your classes are not closed in your span!